# Django retrieve GET list

Tags: django, list, url

I'm new with Django and I have a URL list such as:

```
example.com?item=test&item=for&test=url
```

I know how to retrieve this value in the view:

```
a = request.GET.getlist('item')
```

My problem is: How can I retrieve this list in the template?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass to template through template context.

e.g

```
def myview(request):
    a = request.GET.getlist('item')
    ...
    ctx = {'myitems': a}
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', ctx)
```

In template:

```
{% for item in myitems %}
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: okay it's a solution, but is their any reason to request.GET.getlist.item doesn't work in the template like other case ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list using this:

```
{% for e in request.GET.lists %}{% if e.0 == 'item' %}{{ e.1 }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

That will display the list you want:

```
['test', 'for', 'url']
```