# How to parse request in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Hi i am making an webserver , In which I have to hit some request from html page and return the response. The URL which is generated using html is

http://192.168.2.253:8080/searchSMS/?KPImsgId=0&circle=&subId=&startDate=DD-MM-YYYY&endDate=DD-MM-YYYY&Username=ashish

but in the server side I am not able to see the request data. I am using 
`q = QueryDict(request.body)` but it is showing `<QueryDict: {}>`

How to find the all the parameters coming in request.

Answer (score 7):

In your case you send the data in url so access the data through `request.GET` as follow:

```
username = request.GET.get('Username')
start_date = request.GET.get('startDate')
# ... the same for all the other parameter after the `?` marque.
```

In fact there is a difference between `request data`, `request.body`, `request.GET` and `request.POST`:

- If you are sending POST request to django **function view** or **class based view**: you access the request data in `request.body` or `request.POST`.
- If you are sending POST request to Django REST Framework: you access the data in `request.data`. You may also find in Internet `request.DATA` that correct but it's deprecated in the newer version of DRF in favor of request.data.
- If you send parameter in the url like in you case, you access the data form `request.GET` as explained above.

Comment: i got your point but how to get in this case `http://192.168.2.253:8080/searchCall/?startDate=DD-MM-YYYY&endDate=DD-MM-YYYY&reportingType=0&circle=0&kpi=107&kpi=121` I can get more than one kpi

Comment: The parameter are send as keys of a dictionary, so if there is a duplicate only one will be considered. So either you send them with different name or in list. Check this post for more details about [using a list or not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9176496/5658350)

Comment: can't I do `QueryDict(request.body)` in this after changing names.

Comment: `request.body` contains only the data send in the body of a POST request but it can not contain the url parameters.

Comment: so that means I dont have any way to do it :(

Comment: I just want to check the parameters coming from url request.

Comment: @DhiaTN it is not true that only one value per key will be considered. It is perfectly valid to send multiple values; in which case you can use `request.GET.getlist('param_name')` to get them all as a list.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman I already mention that in the comment above in the link: `?id[]=101404&id[]=7267261`

Comment: But that is not true. In Django there is no need to use that PHP/Rails format; `id=123&id=456` works fine.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, I got it. I did not know about `GET.getlist`,@AshishK. check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12955933/5658350) this is what Daniel is talking about